# web3 .toNumber is not a function error

Tags: web3js

Strange thing happens with `.toNumber` function. It works well for account balance, but not for **rate** / **endTime**. I can't understand why, because balance is BigNumber and rate property is BigNumber (you can see screenshot). Has anyone similar issue and how it needs to be solved?
I use Truffle 4 + VS Code.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Account balance returns *BigNumber*.

`call`s actually return a *Promise*.

If you do something like this, you should get the result in the console:

```
ico.rate.call().then(result => result.toNumber())
```

Comment: :) Thanks! I tried with **this**, but have made typo `ico.rate.call().then(result = result.toNumber())`. **=** instead of **=>** :) What a relief...